# i get Error while trying to compile and Run, [Linker error] undefined reference to `scand'

Tags: c, scanf, dev-c++

---

So i am making a Program using Dev C++ and here is the Program works:

---

Allow user to enter a weight in pounds then your program will convert the value into kilograms and grams.

Allow a user to enter a height in centimeters then your program will convert it to meters, feet and inches.

and my code in Dev C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CENTIMETER 0.01
#define POUNDS 0.453592
int main (void) 
{
         float Pounds;
         float Kilograms;
         float Grams;
         float Centimeters;
         float Meters;
         float Feet;
         float Inches;

         printf("Please Enter your weight in Pounds : ");
         scanf("%f",&Pounds);
         Kilograms=Pounds*POUNDS;
         Grams=Kilograms*1000;
         printf(" Weight in kilograms is %.2f", Kilograms);
         printf(" Weight in grams is %.2f", Grams);
         printf("\n\n\n\n\n\nAnd ");
         printf("Please Enter your height in Centimeters: ");
         scand("%f",&Centimeters);
         Meters=Centimeters*CENTIMETER;
         Feet=Meters*3.28084;
         Inches=Feet*12;
         printf(" Height in Meters is %.2f", Meters);
         printf(" Height in Feet is %.2f", Feet);
         printf(" Height in Inches is %.2f", Inches);

         getch();
         return 0;
         }
```

and the problem is i can't save it and it said:

 
 "[Linker error] undefined reference to `scand' " , 

 " ld returned 1 exit status" 

am new into programming, so i hope someone can help me..

Comment: `scand("%f",&Centimeters);` --> `scanf("%f",&Centimeters);`, and `getch()` is not a standard function, use `getchar()`

Comment: Look at the error. Nothing shocking you when you see "scand" ?

Comment: if u want to use getch(),the include the header file #include<conio.h>

Comment: AlterMann and Pankaj Andhale, Thanks you so much for the BIG HELP! It works Thank you :D am glad you understand my problem. :) Thanks, am just new in programming hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains a typo. In this statement

```
scand("%f",&Centimeters);
```

there shall be `scanf` instead of `scand`.

```
scanf("%f",&Centimeters);
```